# Update JSONB column by values from another table columns with nulls in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have two tables A_table and B_table with relation one-to-many and want to add a column with type JSONB to table A_table based on values from table B_table. I use following code:

```
UPDATE A_table a
 SET new_json_col = json_build_object(
   "key1", b.col1,
   "key2", b.col2,
   "key3", b.col3,
   "key4", b.col4,
   "key5", b.col5,
   "key6", b.col6,
   "key7", b.col7,
   "key8", b.col8
   )
   FROM B_table b
   WHERE a.id = b.a_id;
```

and getting error `error: argument 7 cannot be null` and `hint: 'Object keys should be text.'`
I use typeorm with nodejs for running migrations.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use single quotes for `key1` - `key8`, not double. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For keys single quotes should be used. Thanks @Stefanov.sm

```
UPDATE A_table a
 SET new_json_col = json_build_object(
   'key1', b.col1,
   'key2', b.col2,
   'key3', b.col3,
   'key4', b.col4,
   'key5', b.col5,
   'key6', b.col6,
   'key7', b.col7,
   'key8', b.col8
   )
   FROM B_table b
   WHERE a.id = b.a_id;
```